# Cannot print help topic on exported rcp product

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

When I try to print an help topic using the embedded help system my eclipse app, nothing happens and the help freezes until I close the app manually.

Strange thing is printing works perfectly when I run my application directly in Eclipse but not working when I launch the exported product.

It's like the Windows standard printing modal is launched but no shown..

Does someone know how to fix that ?

Note : I'm using Eclipse RCP 3.X with E4 compatibility layer

Comment: Any errors showing up in the .log file?  If so, please post them.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error in log. My app behaves like everything is fine except help does not show up.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the help content from a stand alone browser?  Just right click on a link in the embedded browser (IE when using Windows), select Properties, and copy the link.  They paste the link into a stand alone browser and see if the print button works.

Comment: Yes! By using IE or Chrome, help content is well displayed and we can print it (this is actually my workaround for my users...).